# error at a simple grafic programm on java

Tags: java

This is an error: java:6:25:
Name 'Overrust' must match pattern '^[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$'.
 that I get when I try to run this. Any ideas on how to fix it?

```
 import java.awt.Color;
    import java.awt.Graphics;
    import java.awt.Graphics2D;
    import java.awt.Rectangle;
    public class Conferval {
        public static void  Overrust(Graphics x) {
            Graphics2D box = (Graphics2D) x;
            Graphics2D line = (Graphics2D) x;
            Graphics2D point = (Graphics2D) x;
            box.setColor(Color.GRAY);
            box.draw(new Rectangle(75, 98, 14, 14));
            line.setColor(Color.ORANGE);
            line.drawLine(29, 2, 194, 119);
            point.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            point.drawLine(120, 4, 120, 5);
        }
    }
```

Comment: That error is being generated in a non-standard toolchain. `Overrust` is an acceptable (although not conventional) method name.

Answer (score 0):

Change the name Overrust to overrust (notice the lowercase first letter).

Comment: Yes, I already tried this. When I do it the error is: the method is not found: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Conferval.Overrust(java.awt.Graphics)

Comment: Thats because You need to change the code where you invoke the method to match the "new" method name.

Comment: public static void  Overrust(Graphics x)
You mean in that line? Beacause I've changed it and still doesn't work.

Comment: When I compile in cmd with javac it shows the following error: Class names, 'Conferval', are only accepted if annotation processing is explicitly requested
1 error